# Convert DateTime to UTC when using FromForm

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

How to properly convert date received in form data? Im writing web API and i have endpoint in controller that gets file FromForm and date FromForm.

When i pass date using FromBody, its JSON and i can just add CustomDateTimeConverter class deriving from JsonConverter to JsonOptions in startup class. In this class i can override read and write methods for example:

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
     writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToUniversalTime());
}
```

Now every request with date is properly converted if its FromBody, but how to achieve the same using **FromForm**? JsonConverter is not used when data is passed as FormData and date received in application is diffrent than what i sent from postman (shifted by 2 hours).